# Архитектура модульной системы

Tags: c++, шаблоны-проектирования

## Ситуация

*В дальнейшем под модулями я подразумеваю члены класса Base, являющиеся указателями на другие классы*

Имеется класс, состоящий из произвольного количества модулей

```
class Base {
public:
    ModuleOne * mod1;
    ModuleTwo * mod2;
    ...
};
```

Каждый из модулей имеет свой набор **различных** методов, в том числе публичных, которые могут вызываться из различных участков кода. Для простоты скажем, что все методы void.

## Задача

Реализовать структуру **Base** c удобным способом включения/выключения модулей, а именно:

1. Идеальный вариант: в отключенном состоянии описание модуля и все вызовы методов не компилируются
2. Хороший вариант: модуль компилируется, все вызовы методов заменяются на пустышки
3. Как можно меньше дополнительного кода для каждого вызова метода модуля или внутри модуля
4. Удобство вызова методов

## Мои попытки

- ## #ifdef

Включение и выключение методов реализуется с помощью

```
#define MODULE1
```

и все вызовы методов, описания модулей оборачиваются в

```
#ifdef MODULE1
... // вызов или описание
#endif
```

**Плюсы:** лишний код не компилируется, всё работает как часы

**Минусы:** нагромождение конструкций ifdef делает код почти нечитабельным

- ## #define CALL(...)

Все вызовы методов обернуть в макрос вида

```
#define CALL(obj, f, args) (obj->*f)(args)
```

который будет себя вести по-разному, в зависимости от того же

```
#define MODULE1
```

**Плюсы:** немного кода, компилятор оптимизирует и удалит лишние методы

**Минусы:** слабочитабельно, подсветка синтаксиса тупит

- ## Обертка в виде класса

Попытка реализовать класс-обертку через перегрузку -> и дополнительную внутреннюю структуру:

```
Proxy<Module> module(new Module());
module->CALL(&Module::Print);
```

Включение и выключение предполагается через type_traits

**Плюсы:** как и с макросом CALL

**Минусы:** слабочитабельно (но лучше макроса), подсветка синтаксиса всё еще тупит, требуется полное название метода в аргументе

---

Меня не покидает чувство, что существует особный паттерн для моей задумки. Думаю, средствами C++11/14 это можно реализовать проще, чем я описал.

---

**UPD1:**
Желание компилировать только вызываемый код - это только желание. Если он не будет вызываться, то компилятор сам с этим должен справиться.

Пример кода модуля в реализации с #ifdef

**config.h**

```
#pragma once
#define MODULE_ONE
#define MODULE_TWO
//#define MODULE_THREE
```

**ModuleOne.h**

```
#include "config.h"

#ifdef MODULE_ONE
class ModuleOne {
    int important_value;
public:
    void SaveImportantValue(int v) { important_value = a; };
};
#endif
```

**Base.cpp**

```
void Base::MakeSomething() {
    int a;
    ... // вычисления
    #ifdef MODULE_ONE
    mod1->SaveImportantValue(a);
    #endif
    ...
}
```

На ум пришла еще одна идея, помимо описанных выше: единый для модулей родитель Module (не абстрактный) со всевозможными пустыми методами (return ...), которые существуют в модулях. Соответственно, всё делается виртуальным.

```
class Base {
    std::vector<Module*> _modules;
public:
    template <class T>
    T* GetModule() {
        ModuleOne * ret;
        for (auto m : _modules)
            if ((ret = dynamic_cast<T*>(m)) != nullptr)
                return ret;
        return Module::GetInstance(); // пустой экземпляр
    }
};
```

Что имеем? Следующий код

```
GetModule<ModuleOne>()->DoSomething();
```

будет выполнять полезную работу, только если сам модуль добавлен в конструкторе Base. Остаётся лишь с помощью #define/type_traits реализовать включение в конструкторе только определенных модулей. Если это можно еще упростить, с радостью выслушаю советы.

Comment: Я правильно понял суть, что Вы хотите такой организации программы, чтобы компилировался только реально вызываемый (используемый)  код? Если да, то для начала просто обратите внимание на `static inline` функции (и делайте конкретную вещь, а не всеобъемлющий фреймворк)

Comment: Макросы на вызов модуля, макросы на определение модуля в классе. Больше никак. Это будет наиболее чистое решение. Но макросы и IntelliSense это всегда проблема. Но Вы уже придумали себе проблему, поэтому придётся выбирать, что Вам предпочтительнее.